# Custom post type redirected to homepage - how to debug

Tags: custom-post-types, query, redirect

I have a custom post type, when I try to display the post, I get redirected to the homepage. The same happens to my blog posts

I enabled Twenty Eleven theme, that works fine, so there's a problem with the theme I'm using.

I was trying to debug query vars using

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','test_aaa',1);
function test_aaa() {
    global $wp_query;
    var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
    die('');
}
```

That always gives me `page_id = 60`, which is my homepage. How can I debug this and find out what is wrong?

This are the complete query vars I'm getting:

```
array(53) { ["page"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> string(2) "60" ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["embed"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_name__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Comment: The `query_vars` seem to be empty, so that would indeed lead you to the home page. What is the code generating the `query_vars`?

Comment: I guess the redirect happens sooner than the pre_get_posts is firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The staple technique to debug an unwanted redirect is to interrupt it in process and dump a call stack of where it's initiated from.

Outside of just doing it by hand by troubleshooting WP core's redirect functions, there are some ready made solutions. [Better HTTP Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-http-redirects/) is one plugin I've used on multiple occasions for it, it has debug mode that will do just that.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thanks, great suggestion, great plugin.